# if statement not working, outputs else statement instead

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I'm trying to output the if statement, but instead the else statement shows. I have created a page using Wordpress and assigned this template to the page. I'm trying to show product image and content if number of products is > 0, which it is. But instead it shows the else statement. Can someone please help?

```
<?php  
/*
Template Name: Product Single Template
*/
$productsPermalink = pods_var('last', 'url');
$singleProductPod = pods('products', $productsPermalink);
$numProducts = $singleProductPod->total();
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<section>
<?php  if($numProducts > 0): 
?>

    <h1><?php echo $singleProductPod->field('name'); ?></h1>

    <div class="instructor single">
        <img src="<?php echo $singleProductPod->field('image.guid') ?>" alt="<?php echo $singleProductPod->field('name')?>">
        <p><?php echo $singleProductPod->field('content')?></p>
    </div>


<?php  else: ?>
    <h3>There is no such product: <?php echo $productsPermalink; ?>, please select another product</h3>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Simple answer : `$numProducts` is not > 0

Comment: What is the value of `$numProducts`? It is clearly less than one. The problem is not the if, it is somewhere around here: `$singleProductPod->total();`. Go through the three lines of code there and make sure that `$productsPermalink` and `$singleProductPod` actually contains what you expect them to contain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably shows the if statement because in the line `<?php  if($numProducts > 0):` **you have the condition that if the value `$numProducts` is less than `0` it should instead execute the `else` clause.**

Try and use `die (var_dump ($numProducts));` to see the output and find out what really is going on.
While you're at it try using `var_dump` on `$singleProductPod->total();` as well.

Maybe you'll find out that the values of these variables isn't quite what you thought it would be.

Comment: Thank you, I found out it was returning NULL after testing with var_dump :)